# Передать результат запроса mysql из класса передать в переменную и вызвать на другой странице

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, классы

У меня есть класс, где я собираю все комментарии. потом мне надо в другую страницу вставить эти комментарии, но т.к. делаю шаблон, у меня сам запрос к бд и результат запроса сохраняются в функции класса, а потом я его просто вызываю на странице и вставляю значения куда надо (двумерный массив).

в классе

```
public function GetComments(){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");
        return mysql_fetch_row($result);
    }
```

а уже на странице я получила и запомнила в переменную результат функции и вывожу

```
<?php  
         foreach ($allComments as $value) 
              { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$value;?></td>
                <td><?=$value;?></td>
                <td><?=$value;?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }  ?>
```

но так передается в $allComments только 1 строка запроса. если я в функции не вставляю mysql_fetch_row, то возвращается ресурс (а мне бы массив). 
как бы мне исправить все это дело. всю голову сломал

UPD. вопрос решен

Comment: Сорри за оффтоп но вас точно Костя завут? Ну и покажите решение?

Answer (score 1):

Странно видеть такое в 2016 году. Пожалуйста используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) или посмотрите в сторону фреймворков. (Например LARAVEL5 или Yii2).

Comment: Но это же комментарий а не ответ.

Comment: "UPD. вопрос решен" прямо под вопросом. А я дал совет, чтобы человек копал в правильном направлении.

Comment: Проголосовал за, но чтобы он копался в правильном направление я бы всё же привёл конкретный пример использования. Ну и `фрамворк` как то режит глаза мож всё таки лучше `фреймворк`

Comment: Возможно вы правы. Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для тех, кому ответ на вопрос "Я возвращаю из функции только одну строку результата. Почему функция возвращает мне всегда только одну строку?" все еще не очевиден, и хочет узнать таинственное решение, ниже следует сеанс разоблачения черной магии.

Для презираемого всеми mysql ext:

```
$return = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $return[] = $row;
}
return $return;
```

для никем не понимаемого mysqli

```
return $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM comments")->fetch_all();
```

для рекомендуемого PDO

```
return $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM comments")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: лучше уберите mysql_query из виду. Чтобы не копировали плохие примеры для старых версий php.